# Deadlock in System.Diagnostic.Process

Tags: c#, cmd, process, command-prompt

I have a small console application and I want to read the output in C#. Therefore I've created this code snippet. The command prompt opens, but nothing is displayed.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.StartInfo.FileName = DirectoryPath + "Test.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-showAll";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(2000);
String strOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

If I remove `UseShellExecute`, `RedirectStandardOutput` and the last line, the command prompt opens and the `Test.exe` is shown, but I need the output as String and so I have to use these attributes to read the `StandardOutput`

I've also tried to set a timeout of 2 seconds (`process.WaitForExit(2000)`), but the empty command prompt does not close after 2 seconds.

If I close the empty command prompt manually in debug mode, the variable strOutput has my requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid deadlock you have to read the output stream before you wait to exit. So try :

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = DirectoryPath + "Test.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-showAll";
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.Start();
    String strOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
```